# Phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I just started developing application. I read tons of documentation about portability and so on. I decided phonegap with JQ mobile, but I cannot understand some steps.

1. I know I can use PG over jq mobile, but what about IDE? someone said, they used DW 6 as IDE, but why need eclipse also?
2. If I can write a small drag and drop calculator, why should I use phonegap?

I think that worst part of this, is that one can solve problems in different ways, but which one is perfect don't understand.

What and how should I use DW 6 and JQ mobile together with phonegap, if necessary?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only pre DW6 versions needed a Eclipse/XCode, DW6 has an official Phonegap plugin.

   http://phonegap.com/2012/04/24/adobe-dreamweaver-cs6-supports-phonegap-build/
2. If you want to deploy your web app as a standalone mobile app you need phonegap (or rhomobile) to wrap your HTML/CSS/JS into a working hybrid mobile application. On the other hand, you dont need Phonegap if you want to deploy it on your web site.

   Take a look here to find how:

   http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/using-the-phonegap-build-panel-in-dreamweaver-cs6-to-build-native-applications-for-android-and-ios-devices/

   and

   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngLTIV9izds